# Valid Move method for Tic Tac Toe in Java

Tags: java

I have got an assignment to develop tic tac toe game but my `isValidMove` method creates trouble. It replaces the symbol even after testing `isValidMove` method. Actually, it never goes and checks the 'if' condition in `isValidMove` method.

```
public boolean executeMove(String move, Player p)
{
    int row;
    int col;
    row = (int)(move.charAt(0)-'0');
    col = (int)(move.charAt(1)-'0');

    if(isValidMove(move) == false)  
    {
        board[row-1][col-1]= p.getSymbol();
        printBoard();
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean isValidMove(String move)
{
    int row = (int)(move.charAt(0)-'0');
    int col = (int)(move.charAt(1)-'0');
        if(board[row-1][col-1] == ' ')
        {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

PS: If someone can tell me.. the program enters name of players as string but prints the address rather than printing name.. what to do?

Comment: Why do you check `if(isValidMove(move) == false)` shouldn't this be `if(isValidMove(move))`?

Comment: if i change if(isValidMove(move) == false) to if(isValieMove(move)) then it doesnt print the board.. otherwise it does
actually its always returning false from isValidMove() method

Comment: How is board variable declared?

Comment: its a 2D char array
private char[][] board = new char[3][3];

Comment: Try debugging by printing out contents of the `board[row-1][col-1]` before you execute the if statement.

Comment: board[row-1][col-1] stores the symbol as its set equal to p.getSymbol()
and yeah it prints the symbol.. before as well as after if statement
the issue is.. it replaces the symbol on same location while it shud not

Comment: I meant to say that does it print `' '` before the if statement - the condition of the loop?

Comment: also use @blip while you respond to my comments. This will notify me as soon as you post your comment

Comment: @Blip if u are talking about that ' 'if if condition of isValidMove() then no it doesn't print it
' ' is there to check if the location is empty or not

Comment: @Masu: It seems that problem is either with initialization of `board` array or method `getSymbol` of `Player` class. It will be easy to find out exact  problem if you provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what i meant was add `System.out.println(board[row-1][col-1])` just before `if(board[row-1][col-1] == ' ')` and see whether `' '` is printed out when you want to have the `if(board[row-1][col-1] == ' ')` executed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your `executeMove()` must return `true` only if the move is legally performed. But you return `true` even for illegal moves.

```
public boolean executeMove(String move, Player p) {
    int row;
    int col;
    row = (int)(move.charAt(0)-'0');
    col = (int)(move.charAt(1)-'0');

    boolean valid = isValidMove(move);       // <-- remember is the move valid
    if (valid) {
        board[row-1][col-1] = p.getSymbol(); // <-- place symbol only if move is valid
    } 
    printBoard();
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: if i change if(isValidMove(move) == false) to if(isValieMove(move)) then it doesnt print the board.. otherwise it does
actually its always returning false from isValidMove() method

Comment: You want to print the board in both legal and illegal moves? If yes, see updated answer.

Comment: it does not print any symbol on board if i write the updated code

i do not want the symbol already on board to be removed after next symbol is entered.
but it gets replaced according to my code

Comment: @Masu: Make sure every element of board array is initialized with `' '`.

Comment: @user148865 yes it is initialized in another method